# Dynamic Content not loading in NextJs Dynamic Pages

Tags: next.js, strapi

Currently I have a Blogs collection type in my Strapi CMS with an Id and title data fields. I'm using NextJs for my frontend to dynamically load blog content for each blog page. But my content doesn't load when my dynamic page is loaded.

Page where individual blogs are stored:

```
{posts &&
        posts.map((item, idx) => (
          <Link href={`/BlogPage/${item.id}`}>
            <div>
              <img src={`http://localhost:1337${item.Thumbnail.url}`}/>
            </div>
          </Link>
```

Then inside my BlogPage directory i have a file [id].js:

```
export default function name({blog}) {
    return (
      <>     
      <div>
        {blog.Title}
      </div>
</>
)}
// Tell nextjs how many pages are there
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  const paths = posts.map((blog) => ({
    params: { id: blog.id.toString() },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

// Get data for each individual page
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/blogs?id=${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  const posts = data[0];

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

This takes me to this URL `http://localhost:3000/BlogPage/1` and gives me an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to out the getStaticProps and getStaticPaths of name function

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  const paths = posts.map((blog) => ({
    params: { id: blog.id.toString() },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/blogs?id=${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  const posts = data[0];

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}

export default function name({posts }) { // change this line
    return (
      <>     
      <div>
        {posts.Title} // change this line // Are you sure is it Title? not title? if it is with lowercase, it will return null
      </div>
     </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Oh yes posts worked. Thanks. But still i was using .map(blog) so why is it taking posts.title?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean exactly, if you are talking about why change from (blog) to (posts), simply bes getStaticProps you are passing to the page component as props. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#example